# Structs in C, compiler error

Tags: c, struct

I get this error:

```
str.c:5:19: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'struct'
```

when compiling the following code. What is wrong with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct addpoints (struct point p1, struct point p2){
    p1.x += p2.x;
    p1.y += p2.y;
    return p1;
}

int main(){
    struct point{
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    struct point p1 = { 13, 22 };
    struct point p2 = { 10, 10 };

    addpoints (p1,p2);

    printf("%d\n", p1.x);

}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! This example is from the book "The C programming language" and it appears there is an error in this example. I had tried to add the return type `struct point` but recieved the same error until I pulled out the `struct point` definition out of main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct addpoints (struct point p1, struct point p2){
```

`struct` is not a type. `struct point` is a type.

Also declare your `struct point` type before using it, here you are declaring `struct point` in  `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want `addpoints` to return a `struct point`, but you forgot to put in `point` after `struct`:

```
struct point addpoints (struct point p1, // ...
```

However, this will still not work unless you pull your definition of `struct point` out of `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct point addpoints (struct point p1, struct point p2){
    p1.x += p2.x;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Many problems:

```
struct addpoints (struct point p1, struct point p2){
    p1.x += p2.x;
    p1.y += p2.y;
    return p1;
}
```

At the first glance, I was surprised, I don't remember C has this syntax? I must be stupid again. Then I see, it is a function, and return type is struct, which is apparently wrong.

struct is a keyword to declare a struct, not a type. If you want to return a struct type, you need the struct name. In your case, you should use:

```
struct point addpoints(struct point p1, struct point p2){//...}
```

Also your `struct point` is inside your main function, not global. So a global function like `addpoints` cannot access it. You must take it outside, and has to be before function addpoints. Because C parser uses up-to-down to parse the code. If you have something that never appear before the usage, it will tell you, `first declaration of something`