# Errata of K&R book on C programming

Tags: c, struct

I am going through the K&R book{2nd Addition} on C lang. 
On Page No 107, I found that struct type "Point" is missing form the "return type" of the "addpoint" function. 
From The Book

```
/* addpoints: add two points */

 struct addpoint(struct point p1, struct point p2)
 {
 p1.x += p2.x;
 p1.y += p2.y;
 return p1;
 }
```

Was expecting something like

```
    struct point addpoint(struct point p1, struct point p2)
{
.
.
.
```

Is my understand correct when I say "point" is missing from return type? What are other errata that I need to look for in this book? 
I found this link
http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html
,Is this complete list? If someone can point me more examples like this it will be good.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Structs in C, compiler error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113171/structs-in-c-compiler-error)

Comment: Thanks Adam, Yes it is duplicate..

Comment: I have aleady falged this question. Hopefully it will be removed soon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not missing since p1 is defined as struct point in the paramter, also I've looked up the K&R and the addpoint is defined as `struct point addpoint(struct point p1,struct point p2);`

Comment: Thanks BsD.. I think I should delete this question in that case. Looks like my book is not perfectly updated.

Answer (score 0):

OP you're quite right, the "point" is missing. I **guess** early compilers were probably permissive enough that this sort of thing slipped through the cracks.

I don't think you can guarantee any errata list is complete, but this book has been around for so long I think pretty much all the main problems would have been spotted. Having said that, i never noticed the problem you pointed out just now.

If you're that concerned, i suggest that you should be suspicious of everything, and compile and run all programs using a recent C89 compiler at the strictest possible levels of conformance.

Comment: actually I compiled it and checked with my MS VC++ setup and it gave type error when I miss "point" in type. Just wanted to be 100% sure abt it.